# Schedule an insert into NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone, nsmutablearray

I am working on a game for iOS and I have to schedule an NSMutableArray addobject to be able to see my animation.

```
[monster stopAllActions];
[monster startDeathAction];
[monsterToDelete addObject: lilMonster];
```

I stop all actions on the monster object, then start the death animation and then I insert it into an array to delete it. The fact is that I cannot see the animation because it instant-deletes the monster.

I have been trying to schedule that addObject but I cannot find a way to do it.

Can I have some help from you? Thanks :)

In short: i want to wait an animation to finish to do a [array addObject: object];

PS: I didn't mention it. I am working with Cocos2d

Comment: 'CCAnimation *explosionAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:explosionFrames delay: 0.15f];
    self.explosionAction =[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:explosionAnim restoreOriginalFrame:NO]; 'This is how I am handling my animations. Anims are working well, I just need to schedule that at the end of the second. If I comment the [monsterToDelete addObject: lilMonster] it works fine but does not remove the monster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options here:

OPTION 1:Add a variable to monster that will basically tell if it's death action has finished. Set it to true when you want to delete it. You'll also have to modify the code that cleans up the monstersToDelete array to only delete the monsters that have their death action finished.

OPTION 2: Make the monster call a delegate when the death action is done. Something like:

```
- (void) startDeathAction : (id) target : (SEL) sel
{
   Action* myCurrentAction = ...// your death action here
   [self runAction:[CCSequenceAction actionWithActions: myCurrentAction,[CCCallFunc actionWithTarget: target selector:sel ]];
}
```

and on the code where you are starting the death action add

```
[monster stopAllActions];
[monster startDeathAction: self : @selector(onMonsterDeath)];
...
- (void) onMonsterDeath
{
    [monsterToDelete addObject: lilMonster];
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this comment but, how can I pass monsterToDelete and lilmonster to onMonsterDeath?

Comment: Well, i guess you would have to either save monstersToDelete as a variable of the class instead of a function variable. And you could pass the lil monster variable to the onMonsterDeath by calling CCCallFuncN, which will add a "sender" variable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on how you're performing your animations, but if you are using one of the `UIView` methods, such as:

```
+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration animations:(void (^)(void))animations completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion
```

you could use the completion block to delete your monster.

Comment: CCAnimation *explosionAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:explosionFrames delay: 0.15f];
    self.explosionAction =[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:explosionAnim restoreOriginalFrame:NO]; This is how I am handling my animations. Anims are working well, I just need to schedule that at the end of the second. If I comment the [monsterToDelete addObject: lilMonster] it works fine but does not remove the monster

Answer (score 0):

If you have an event on animation end, you can try and register a delegate function that adds the object to the array.

This way the object would be deleted right after it finished playing the animation.